# VPN access configuration with ForeFront TMG

Tags: vpn, microsoft-forefront, microsoft-ftmg-2010

I am trying to configure VPN Client access with Microsoft ForeFront TMG 2010. When I try to add domain groups to allow access to them, under Group column I can only see the SID of the domain group. And the Domain column ends up empty. Microsoft ForeFront TMG 2010 is joined to the domain.

Can you think of a reason?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and found errors in the log that the trust relationship between AD and the TMG host was broken. It turned out to be a DNS problem as I also had DNS entries on the external NIC. Just make sure to have only one DNS entry to the AD server on the internal NIC. That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unjoin and rejoin the domain. Can you access Active Directory? Are there any related events in the event log (about processing group policies etc.)?